# Captial P dangit

Tags: discussion

...or why everybody who was against it failed. When Google agrees to even modify the string to fit the brands spelling, then you know it's too late.

> [image: Google even translates it into a Capital P.]

Answer (score 4):

I'm against it, and I haven't failed. The filters on my own site still work just fine. ;)